# node.js - perform global procedure before invoke the mapped methods

Tags: node.js, express

everyone ! I've this sentence in my app.js:

```
app.get('/aux/:subject/:data', aux.query);
app.post('/register/:Id', register.create);
app.post('/register/:Id/smsConfirm', register.confirmSms);
app.post('/register/:Id/login', register.login);
app.post('/register/:Id/resetPassword', register.resetPassword);
app.get('/register/:Id/getSms', register.getSms);
```

And I will have much more because it's the beginning. And i'd like to implement a global function to be executed before any class like aux.query, register.create, etc be invoked.

Basically I'd like to check if the IP is on my black list. If true: Don't execute anything - Throw a 403 instead.
Actually the only way I know to implement this is to put in any method a verification using promises and after check, allow the execution, but I believe that there is a better way to do the things in a global way (maybe not ??)
Can someone give me a good hint ? ty !

Answer (score 0):

You should handle your black list check as middleware if it is a valid test for every endpoint.

```
function blacklist(req, res, next) {
  // check blacklist
  // call next() if passed
  next();
}

app.use(blacklist);

app.get('/aux/:subject/:data', aux.query);
app.post('/register/:Id', register.create);
app.post('/register/:Id/smsConfirm', register.confirmSms);
app.post('/register/:Id/login', register.login);
app.post('/register/:Id/resetPassword', register.resetPassword);
app.get('/register/:Id/getSms', register.getSms);
```